# pass a form value to another form on a different page without using url variables (javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form on a page and I want to pass a form inputbox value to another inputbox on another form on another page without using URL variables - is this possible?

They both share the same header page section if that is of any help.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on @BoltBait - this is a basic example, using JQuery + the [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie)

On the first page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // set the cookie, on click to the next page
    $("#next-page").click(function() {
        $.cookie("INPUTBOX",$("input[name=inputbox]").val());
    });
</script>
```

And on the next page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // get the cookie, we are now on the next page
    alert($.cookie("INPUTBOX"));
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a cookie, if both pages are on the same web server.